# Keep getting max update exceeded error but cannot seem to find error in code

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have made forms like this before but I seem to be missing something in this one. I keep getting the error "maximum update depth exceeded error" but I dont see where I am goin wrong and I've spent too much time looking at it. I already tried to change my `onChange` to include an arrow because others have suggested to do so , but when that happens I cant type in the input boxes. like so
`onChange={()=>this.handleChange("username")}`
I should note that I only get the error when I try to register the user and not when I type into the input. Here is the full error as well.

```
    at checkForNestedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:23804)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21836)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.development.js:12468)
    at Router.Component.setState (react.development.js:366)
    at react-router.js:75
    at listener (history.js:156)
    at history.js:174
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.notifyListeners (history.js:173)
    at setState (history.js:562)



 Here is my code, please help.






import React from "React"

class Splash extends React.Component{ 
    constructor(props) { 
      super(props)
      this.state = this.props.user;
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.clearErrors();
  }
  
  handleSubmit(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.signUp(this.state);
  }

  handleChange(field) {
    return (e) => {
      this.setState({ [field]: e.currentTarget.value })
    };
    
  }

    render() { 
        return (
          <div className="splash-background">
            <div className="modal-screeen">
              <form className="modal" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <h2 className="welcom-text"></h2>
                <input className="user-input" type="text" placeholder="Name" onChange={this.handleChange("name")} value={this.state.name}/>
                <input className="user-input" type="text" placeholder="Email" onChange={this.handleChange("email")} value={this.state.email}/>
                <input className="user-input" type="text" placeholder="Create Username" onChange={this.handleChange("username")} value={this.state.username}/>
                <input className="user-input" type="password" placeholder="Create Password" onChange={this.handleChange("password")} value={this.state.password}/>
                <button>Sign Up</button>
                
              </form>
            </div>
         </div>
        );
    }

}
export default Splash




import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { signup, login, clearErrors } from "../../actions/session_actions.js";
import Splash from "./splash";


const mapStateToProps = ({ errors }) => {
  return {
    errors: errors.session,
    user: {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      name:"",
      email: "",
    },
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    signUp: (user) => dispatch(signup(user)),
    login: (user) => dispatch(login(user)),
    clearErrors: () => dispatch(clearErrors()),
    
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Splash);
```

Comment: Does this happen when component loads or when you start typing ? Also can you paste clearErrors() function code (the one inside dispatch)?

Comment: It happens when I try and submit the form and register a user! I commented out the clear errors for now!

Comment: The only cycle I can think of from this piece of code is due to the `ComponentDidMount` block. If this error happens even after you comment that entire block (`ComponentDidMount` function), then something is wrong in signUp code not here. Besides, the error you are showing is saying something from history.js, so I think the error is occurring when you are redirecting after signup may be to dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is the implementation of redux and react state. If you're using redux to manage the form state then I don't think there is a need to also manage that same state with react.

Try something like this, but keep in mind this code isn't tested.

```
class Splash extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.clearErrors();
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.signUp(this.props.user);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    // here you would have another action to update redux state depending 
    // on which input has changed. You can grab the input name via e.target.name
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="splash-background">
        <div className="modal-screeen">
          <form className="modal" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <h2 className="welcom-text"></h2>
            <input
              className="user-input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Name"
              name="name"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              value={this.props.user.name}
            />
            <input
              className="user-input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Email"
              name="email"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              value={this.props.user.email}
            />
            <input
              className="user-input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Create Username"
              name="username"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              value={this.props.user.username}
            />
            <input
              className="user-input"
              type="password"
              placeholder="Create Password"
              name="password"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              value={this.props.user.password}
            />
            <button>Sign Up</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Splash;
```

When it comes to form data, I find it's easier to manage just with react state. Generally redux is used to manage state that is shared across the whole application/multiple components.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually in my route util file. I had an infinite loop of rerouting!